# SQL query in Access 2007 works, but not when in expression builder in report (results in #name?)

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a saved query in MS Access 2007 named "test".

```
SELECT Count(system_info.id) AS CountOfUnique
FROM system_info;
```

So when I run this, it retuns 172 as expected. That confirms the query runs OK.
The table "system_info" is a linked table to an excel spreadsheet. When I run any queries against that table, they ALL work in query view (datasheet).

However, when I try to reference that query result inside of a report, it doesn't work! 
Here's what I do

1. Create new blank report
2. Create a textbox
3. click the "..." button to launch expression builder
4. Using the expression builder, select the query and insert the result `=[test]![CountOfUnique]`

When I then run the report, the textbox has #Name? inside it.
I've googled to death this issue and some suggest it could be a bug with MS Access 2007 when the query returns zero records. However, I know it returns one! Others have suggested changing the name of the textbox as it may clash with something else. Even when that textbox is on it's own in a brand new report it still doesn't work.

I'm tearing my hair out!! I can use the same method on other tables and I see the numbers, but it seems to be just this system_info table that doesnt work in the report. Is there a setting somewhere I've missed??

Thanks for any info

Comment: What's the recordsource for your report?  Also, what is your experience level with Access reports?

Comment: My level of access reports is minimal - I'm making it up as I go along! I last used Access 97... so it was a while ago! It's slowly coming back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the text box type:

```
=DlookUp("CountOfUnique","Test")
```

Also check out DCount.

Comment: You cannot refer to a query by name in a textbox, DLookUp is a domain aggregate function, which runs the query for you. You counld have used VBA and a recordset, but a domain aggregate function is probably best in this case.

Comment: Great - many thanks! I actually just deleted a subreport from my main report and another of my textfields returned #Name? - so obviously if there is a subform, that's done the source data so referencing it worked. Dlookup is great - many thanks!!

Comment: I've just tried the same DLookup function on another table. This one is returning a query which simply counts the records. '=DLookUp("CountOfOrgName","customer_list QUERY count records")' it returns #Error also when I try to do a DCount the same. Any ideas?!

Comment: Are you sure you have not misspelled anything? You can use DCount against the customer list table `DCount("*","customer list")` or `DCount("ID","customer list")` Note that a count of ID will only count records where ID is not null, wheras * will count all records.

Comment: @Matt Facer, spaces in object names create problems.  Enclose the second name in square brackets so it will be recognized as one "thing". `=DLookUp("CountOfOrgName","[customer_list QUERY count records]")`

Comment: @HansUp I tested, because that is what occurred to me, but it is not true for domain aggregate functions.

Comment: @Remou I see that now, too ... spaces don't matter here.  Must be my reflexive aversion to spaces in names which led me astray.  :-)

Comment: @HansUp Yep, it is odd, even a real no-no like `name` will work in domain aggregates.